# Refresh linkedin user access token without user intervention

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

Is there any way to refresh Linkedin access token by application for authenticated user 
without his intervention?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process will only be 'seamless' if the user is both currently logged in to LinkedIn, and the token has yet to expire:

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token

If either of the above is not ture, then the user must directly re-auth a new token.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I already read it. Not sure how to make it. I tried it without success. What does it mean - the user currently logged in to Linkedin? the meaning is that he doesn't remove his account on Linkedin? Can you please show me by example? (I use php & PECL OAuth).

Comment: Currently logged in meaning that he has a current browser session with LinkedIn.com open - i.e. there are active LinkedIn auth credentials in the browser.